# 2023 - Lightning Web Components and Angular

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning-web-components, locker-service, iframe, angular

We have a 2GP that has a Lightning Component (Aura/Canvas) that displays our content inside of iframes. Our platform makes heavy use of Angular 15 and many Angular components like Angular Materials, NG Bootstrap, Carbon Charts Angular, etc.

Watching the timeline for the load is painful (1.2 seconds go by before our server even gets its first request). Based on the names of the URLs, a lot of it seems to be related to Aura (even though all it's providing us with is an authenticated iframe).

Reading through other posts from several years ago, it seems the world has left Aura behind in favor of LWC. That said, we don't want to rebuild all of our UI components from scratch in LWC.

Has anyone gone through a migration like this? Some of what I read suggested that the Locker Service has a tendency to interfere with some framework's event models (like Svelte).

I'm wondering if there are some simple things we could do to reduce the latency vs. a total rewrite.

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For a simple reduction in latency/load times, you need to deal with "Ahead-of-time (AOT) compilation" (AOT) and "tree-shaking." Basically, Angular bundles tend to be large in size, and those sizes will affect your component's loading time. The thing about LWCs is that the runtime is small, and the component bundles tend to be small. I would argue that, aside from some technical differences, like preferring Material to SLDS, a total port from *insert framework here* to LWC is almost likely worth the cost in development time.

Canvas apps simply cannot load before the parent page loads. That's the nature of iframe apps. If you want to spend time fixing the canvas app, consider [webpack-bundle-analyzer](https://www.npmjs.com/package/webpack-bundle-analyzer), which helps identify which bundles are causing the most problem. The effects gained by such an effort will be limited by the effects of AOT compilation and tree-shaking.  A "total rewrite" sounds daunting, but the efforts more than pay off for themselves.

My 2021 role had me working on a project that was a complete React app. It consisted basically of 2×5MB bundles that had to load for every page. It was slow (5+ seconds per page load) that was barely even helped by cache. I rewrote most of it in LWC, and got the page load times down to 0.2 seconds, including the Lottie animation we had for loading. I honestly almost recommended removing it because it was adding to the load time. It was ultimately rejected as being "too expensive" even though it would have saved our customers minutes per day just in loading times.

You can, of course, load React or Angular onto a component marked with `lwc:dom="manual"`, and it works pretty well. Removing the canvas means your code can load in parallel, often saving up to a second or more in timings to load the components. However, I'd argue that this is still less efficient than simply porting to LWC. LWC is, simply put, one of the best frameworks to use in Salesforce, since it's already used in Salesforce.

> I'm wondering if there are some simple things we could do to reduce the latency vs. a total rewrite.

I've already addressed this, but ultimately, porting to LWC is the preferable option here. Your customers will thank you for the port.

Comment: Seems like there are enough predefined LWC components that we may not need some of the 3rd party libraries we are currently using. Pretty impressed with the number of components they have. I'm sure you're right that the load times would be significantly lower.